# Alternate interpretation of number of degenerate fermions formula in phase space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, superposition, phase-space, pauli-exclusion-principle

I'm writing personnal notes on statistical mechanics and I'm tempted to write something that may turn out to be false.  So I need a confirmation/infirmation and opinions on the following (I suspect it's false, but...).

The number of degenerate fermions inside a volume $V$, at temperature $T = 0$, is found by integration on their phase space because of the Pauli exclusion principle (only one fermion per state) :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
N = \int_0^{p_F} \frac{2 \cdot 4 \pi p^2 \, dp}{(2 \pi \hbar)^3} \, V = \frac{p_F^3 \, V}{3 \pi^2 \, \hbar^3}.
\end{equation}
This allows to find the *Fermi momentum* $p_F$ as a function of the particles density $N/V$.  In principle, this integration makes sense only for a large number of particles : $N \gg 1$.

> Now, I'm tempting to interpret (1) as still valid even for $N = 1$
>   (only one fermion in the box), since quantum mechanics allows
>   superpositions of states for a single particle.  Doing an integral
>   over phase space to find just one particle in the box is weird and
>   shouldn't be valid (from Pauli's principle, this summation makes sense
>   only if $N \gg 1)$.  But in QM, a single particle could be in a
>   superposition of states of different momentum, up to the maximal value
>   allowed (i.e Fermi's momentum).

Is this interpretation viable ?  Or is it completely non-sensical ?

For what is worth, my intuition tells me that this *unconventional* interpretation may be true after all, since there are some "alternative" interpretations of some calculations in statistical mechanics.  But what troubles me is the apparent absence of the Pauli exclusion principle in this interpretation.

In applying the Pauli exclusion principle, we say "only one particle per given state", but in QM we *may* say "several states per particle" !  So this seems to suggest that (1) may still be valid in some way, even for $N = 1$.

---

**EDIT :** Here's a tentative justification that the interpretation may be true in *some way*.

You have a single particle in a rectangular box of sizes $\ell$, at temperature $T = 0$.  From classical mechanics, its average momentum should be 0.  But because of the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, the momentum in the $x$ direction has a *minimal* uncertainty given by
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\Delta p_x \ge \frac{\hbar}{2 \Delta x} \approx \frac{\hbar}{\ell},
\end{equation}
since $\Delta x \approx \frac{\ell}{2}$ (on average).  So the momentum may be anything in this range :
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
-\, \Delta p_{x \, \text{max}} \le p_x \le \Delta p_{x \, \text{max}}.
\end{equation}
Thus, classicaly, the particle occupies a small *fuzzy region* in its phase space.  The volume of that region is given by (1), with $p_F$ replaced by $\sim \Delta p_x$.  The Pauli principle may be satisfied if all other particles are placed alone inside adjacent boxes, so there's only one particle per *quantum* state (i.e a fuzzy region in phase space).

The previous argument can be generalized for any number of particles in the same box of volume $V$ : $N > 1$, by splitting the integral (1) in as much parts that there are fermions.  For $N = 3$ for example (or any other integer) :
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
N = \int_0^{p_1} \dots dp + \int_{p_1}^{p_2} \dots dp + \int_{p_2}^{p_{\text{max}}} \dots dp,
\end{equation}
where $0 < p_1 < p_2$ are completely arbitrary and $p_{\text{max}}$ is the maximal value allowed (Fermi's momentum).  This integral splitting is in agreement  with Pauli's exclusion principle.  Each particle draws a fuzzy region in its phase space (they can't be represented by a point, like in classical mechanics).  So I now strongly believe that (1) is still valid for **any integer** $N$, and not just large numbers $N \gg 1$.

I need opinions on this.

Answer (score 1):

> The number of degenerate fermions inside a volume $V$, at temperature $T = 0$, is found by integration on their phase space because of the Pauli exclusion principle (only one fermion per state)

The ground state of this (non-interacting) system is obtained by "filling" the available energy eigenstates in order of increasing energy until the number of particles in the system has been reached. The energy eigenstates of a spinless particle in a box are given by

$$\phi_{nm\ell}(\mathbf x)= \sqrt{\frac{8}{L_xL_yL_z}} \sin\left(\frac{n \pi x}{L_x}\right)\sin\left(\frac{m \pi y}{L_y}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\ell \pi z}{L_z}\right)$$
$$E_{nm\ell} = \frac{(n^2+m^2+\ell^2)\pi^2 \hbar^2}{2mL^2}$$
Defining $\mathbf k = (k_x,k_y,k_z) \equiv \left(\frac{n\pi}{L_x},\frac{m\pi}{L_y},\frac{\ell\pi}{L_z}\right)$, we may write
$$N = \sum_{|\mathbf k|<k_F} 1$$
as an implicit definition of the Fermi momentum. If we define $\Delta k_i \equiv \frac{\pi}{L_i}$, then we may write this as
$$ N = \frac{L_x L_y L_z}{\pi^3} \sum_{|\mathbf k|<k_F} 1 \cdot \Delta k_x \Delta k_y \Delta k_z \iff \frac{N}{V} = \frac{1}{\pi^3} \sum_{|\mathbf k|< k_F} 1 \cdot \Delta k_x \Delta k_y \Delta k_z$$

At the present moment, this is exact. If we take the limit in which $N$ and $V$ go to infinity such that $n\equiv N/V$ is fixed, then the $\Delta k_i$'s go to zero and we have
$$ n = \frac{1}{\pi^3} \int_{|\mathbf k|< k_F} 1 \cdot \mathrm d^3 k = \frac{1}{\pi^3} \left(\frac{1}{8}\right) \frac{4}{3} \pi k_F^3 = \frac{k_F^3}{6\pi^2}$$

where the factor $1/8$ reflects the fact that the $k_i's$ are all positive, and so the integration yields the volume of the first *octant* of the sphere of radius $k_F$ in momentum space.

In the limit, this expression is also exact. For finite $V$, the error involved in approximating the sum as an integral scales like $N/V^2$, and so we have that
$$\frac{N}{V} = \frac{k_F^3}{6\pi^2} + \mathcal O\big(N/V^2\big)$$

Comment: While I agree with this answer, it doesn't answer the question.  This is just a "classical" (i.e consensual) derivation of the Fermi momentum, by applying the Pauli exclusion principle.  It doesn't say anything about the other non-classical derivation that I want to confirm.

Comment: @Cham I'm not really sure what you mean. The derivation I gave in my answer is purely quantum mechanical - for a particle in a box, integration over momentum is nonsensical because momentum is a discrete variable. It can be *approximated* by integration, but that approximation is inexact except in the thermodynamic limit. Note that the **ground state** of the system is the $N$-particle state obtained by taking the Slater determinant of the $N$ lowest energy single-particle eigenfunctions.

Comment: @Cham The derivation that you go through in your question looks to me to be just handwaving about the uncertainty principle while blending quantum and classical ideas together. I don't see why you would have any confidence at all that the equation you end up with is universally valid even when a more fundamental derivation via quantum mechanics suggests that it is not.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, a single fermion may be in a superposition of many values of $p$. However, when you say that it is at $T=0$ this is no longer true, because by definition it must be in the lowest available state. That is why this whole summation over states procedure works at all. So I believe your claim is incorrect.

Edit: for completeness, I would also point out that the above formula is only valid for free noninteracting fermions. In the general case, one must find the density of states.

Comment: Even at $T = 0$, the Heisenberg principle is valid.  The lowest energy is defined up this uncertainty : $E = E_{\text{min}} \pm \Delta E$.  This is also true for momentum.  So even at $T = 0$, the particle occupies a fuzzy region of its *classical* phase space.  That fuzzy region is a *single* quantum state, while it's a superposition of several *classical* states.

Comment: Also, take note that the temperature is defined for a *mixed state* only, which isn't the same as a linear superposition (a *pure state*, by definition).  So $T = 0$ even for a *pure* state defined by a superposition of several momentum states : \begin{equation}| \psi \rangle = \sum_p c(p) \, | p \rangle, \quad \Rightarrow \quad \rho = | \psi \rangle \langle \psi | \quad \Rightarrow \quad S = -\, \mathrm{Tr}(\rho \, \log{\rho}) = 0, \quad \Rightarrow \quad T = 0. \end{equation}

Comment: @Cham In the context we are talking about, equilibrium thermodynamics, this isn't really correct. For a single fermion in thermal equilibrium with a bath that approaches T=0, that fermion will be in its unique ground state (assuming no ground state degeneracy), not just any pure state.  For a nonzero bath it would indeed be in a thermal mixed state.

Comment: Even in thermal equilibrium, there's an Heisenberg uncertainty on the energy of the ground state.  So even at $T = 0$, there's an uncertainty 0n the momentum.  The particle still occupies a fuzzy region in the classical phase space.  Don't you agree with that ?

Comment: @Cham I don't understand why you talk about the uncertainty principle in this context. A finite $\Delta E$ is only necessary if we want to study processes within a finite time interval. In equilibrium thermodynamics $\Delta t \rightarrow \infty$ so that $\Delta E = 0$: The energies are well defined.

Comment: @LucasBaldo, there's a mistake in your comment.  $\Delta t \rightarrow \infty$ doesn't imply $\Delta E = 0$.  The Heisenberg uncertainty is still satisfied with $\Delta E > 0$ and $\Delta t \rightarrow \infty$: $\Delta t \, \Delta E > \frac{\hbar}{2}$ (trivially!).  In other words:  at zero temperature, you still could have a quantum superposition of states such that $\Delta E \ne 0$.  It is not always true that you get the ground state energy at $T = 0$.  It all depends on how the system is prepared.

Comment: "It is not always true that you get the ground state energy at $T=0$. It all depends on how the system is prepared." What do you mean by $T=0$, then? In order for a system to have well defined temperature $T$ it needs to be in thermal equilibrium, i.e. follow the Boltzman distribution $P \propto e^{-\beta E}$. In the zero temperature limit this means $\lim_{T\rightarrow0} P = 0$ for all energies greater than the ground state energy $E > E_0$. So in order for it to make sense to say a state is at zero temperature it *must* be in thermal equilibrium and in the ground state.

Comment: You can of course consider pure states in superposition of different energies, and as you say, prepare them in experiments. But then it does not make sense to atribute temperature to the state.

Comment: If two systems were both at zero K, and one was not at its minimum energy, it might be possible for heat to flow from one system to the other, violating the laws of thermodynamics (specifically, the zeroth and second).